# Tranpose the table rows to column

Tags: mysql, transpose

I have a table which looks like this:

```
id  response_id     name        value
6   13          gender         female
5   13          workingArea    Sch
3   12          workingArea    IT
4   12          gender         male
```

and I wish to convert into something like this:

```
response_id          workingArea   gender
12                IT           male
13                Sch          female
```

May I know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your first table is SOURCETABLE and your second table is TARGETTABLE

```
INSERT INTO TARGETTABLE(response_id, workingArea, gender)
SELECT a.response_id response_id, 
       a.value workingArea, 
       b.value gender
  FROM SOURCETABLE a, SOURCETABLE b
 WHERE a.response_id = b.response_id
   AND a.name <> b.name
   AND a.name = 'workingArea'
   AND b.name = 'gender'
```

Comment: Nice solution. By the way gender and workingArea was mistaken interchange.

Comment: Does it mean I have to add in SOURCETABLE c, d, e, etc which is proportional to the fields I added?